# How do I find (or create) a File Template override in Panels 3?

Tags: 7, theming, panels, files

So I'm using Panels 3 and Drupal 7 and it makes it damn easy to override the default templates for a taxonomy term template, a node template, even the front page template.  However, I don't see anything on the default panel page admin list that allows me to override the default FILE template.  When I try to Add a New Page and use the file/%file path, the system forbids it, as this URL structure already exists.  How do I harness the power of Panels for other page templates that the Panels module does not offer an override out-of-the-box?

Comment: OK, "there's a module for that": Page Manager Existing Pages.
http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages

This is exactly what you need to use panels for any and every Drupal system path to override any page-level template.

I had trouble finding this for a while because was phrasing my search poorly.  I should have been searching for "Page Manager," not Panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam Friedman points out, there is [Page manager existing pages](http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages), which can do part of what "real" Page manager support can do, but it will not have the same capabilities as say the node/%node template has.

There are two issues that work on "full" support for this. [First](http://drupal.org/node/1058098), and [Second](http://drupal.org/node/1314876).